# Electron app generating one-time access codes vs server generated codes

Tags: authentication, web-application, hardening

I'm designing a kiosk to use one-time SMS codes as a method of authentication. The method I'm using to generate codes happens inside of an Electron application running on a locked down kiosk, hardened and assembled by a Third-Party.

What should I consider when thinking about the security of the one-time access code? There is a way to generate the codes server-side, but **is generating a one-time access code on a kiosk secure**?

Comment: That depends on how it is being generated. What is being used as a source of randomness.

Comment: A 0-left-padded, 6 digit `Math.random()` which is regenerated on failure.